# My Github profile picture has changed since using Github Desktop on Windows?

Tags: github

As seen in the image provided my initial commit is the profile picture I have.
But my subsequent commits is a picture of some guy. Getting freaked out!

Why is it like this all of a sudden? I have not changed my profile picture at all.
I simply downloaded Github for desktop and created a new repo and since committing in the github for desktop application it has switched my profile pic. Why?

[image: Example of commits on Github Windows Desktop]

Comment: There is not image attached in your question, also, consider contact GitHub directly about this issue. Provide as more information as required for reproduce the issue. As is stands this question, it is a very low quality and might be deleted. You can [edit] and improve your question. Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming or programmers tool question. It's a customer service-related question about your specific account at Github. Contact them directly for help.

Answer (score 3):

Check the email associated with your commit. see "[How to see contributor's email address on Git commit chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42957850/6309)" and "[How to get (only) author name or email in git given SHA1?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876744/6309)".

And check your [gravatar profile](https://en.gravatar.com/): it is the service GitHub uses to associate a picture to an email. Look for "gravatar" in the page "[GitHub / Personalizing your profile](https://en.gravatar.com/)"