# Where can I find somone's e-mail inside the commit on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

As I have read, git associates every commit with an e-mail. ( git config --global ... )

If this is true, then I can see everyone else's e-mail on GitHub watching their commits.

Where can I find the email inside the commit?

Comment: Are you trying to view their email from the UI? Is this through their API for some sort of integration?

Comment: Two, actually: author, and committer. Clone the repository and run `git log` with `--pretty=fuller` and you'll see these.

Comment: @torek Is it possible to view these infos on GitHub website as well?

Comment: That's up to GitHub. Consult the GitHub documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see contributor's email address on Git commit chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957392/how-to-see-contributors-email-address-on-git-commit-chain)